# Non-responsive fixed layout is not 940px

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm finding Twitter Bootstrap extremely frustrating because even when using the non-responsive stylesheet, the overall width of the layout exceeds 940px. Twitter bootstrap claims that if you're not using the responsive stylesheet, then 940px is the default width. I'm not using the responsive stylesheet and I am using the fixed columns, but I still find that the width of the layout is closer to 1170px.

My layout has the following structure:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span8"></div>
        <div class="span4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I set the wrapper div's width to 960px (which should be enough to contain both child divs) but the two divs are two wide to be contained inline in the wrapper div. Am I missing something here? According to Bootstrap, an 8 and 4 span div should ultimately only take up 940px. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you use your browser's inspector (Firebug on Firefox, for example) to see what rule (and what stylesheet) is applying the width? I can't provide any other assistance than to say something is making the layout that wide; you need to dig into the CSS to find out where it's coming from.

Comment: It looks like the problem is that that actual width of the span8 element is 640 and the width of the span4 is 320 _without_ the margin. Not sure why this is since I'm using the default widths for Bootstrap.

Comment: You were right jackwanders, my mistake! See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I foolishly forgot to remove a sidebar width style of 340px. It is in fact the correct width with a default non-responsive fixed layout. Sorry to anyone who was genuinely stumped by this!